# PHP Issue with Order by Date in Array

Tags: php

I have a little script on which I am working where I can generate income and expense reports in a nice table, however, I am currently facing some issues with the sort order. Here is my current code:

```
    <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="col-md-12">

            <?php
            $fdate=$_POST['fromdate'];
            $tdate=$_POST['todate'];
            $rtype=$_POST['requesttype'];
            ?>

            <?php
                $source1 = $_POST['fromdate'];
                $date1 = new DateTime($source1);
                $source2 = $_POST['todate'];
                $date2 = new DateTime($source2);

            ?>

            <h5 align="center" style="color:#30a5ff">Expense Report from <?php echo $date1->format('d/m/Y')?> to <?php echo $date2->format('d/m/Y')?></h5>
            <hr />


            <!-- table start--->

            <table class="table table-bordered mg-b-0">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Date</th>
                  <th>Description</th>
                  <th>Category</th>
                  <th style="text-align:right;">Cash In</th>
                  <th style="text-align:right;">Cash Out</th>
                  <th style="text-align:right;background: yellow;">Balance THB</th>

                </tr>
              </thead>

              <?php
                $total_e = 0;
                $userid=$_SESSION['detsuid'];
                $ret=mysqli_query($con,"select * from tblexpense where (ExpenseDate BETWEEN '$fdate' and '$tdate')  && (ExpenseType='Expense') && UserId='$userid' ORDER BY ExpenseDate ASC");
                $cnt=1;
                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ret)) {
                $total_e = $total_e+$row['ExpenseCost']
                ?>

              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td><?php  echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row["ExpenseDate"]));?></td>
                  <td><?php  echo $row['ExpenseItem'];?></td>
                  <td><?php  echo $row['ExpenseCat'];?></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td style="text-align:right;"><?php  echo number_format($row['ExpenseCost'], 2);?> THB</td>
                  <td style="text-align:right;"><?php  echo number_format($row['ExpenseCost'], 2);?> THB</td>
                </tr>
                <?php 
                $cnt=$cnt+1;
                }?>

                 <?php

                $total_i =0;
                $userid=$_SESSION['detsuid'];
                $ret=mysqli_query($con,"select * from tblexpense where (ExpenseDate BETWEEN '$fdate' and '$tdate')  && (ExpenseType='Income') && UserId='$userid' ORDER BY ExpenseDate ASC");
                $cnt=1;
                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ret)) {
                $total_i = $total_i+$row['ExpenseCost'];
                ?>

              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td><?php  echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row["ExpenseDate"]));?></td>
                  <td><?php  echo $row['ExpenseItem'];?></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td style="text-align:right;"><?php  echo number_format($row['ExpenseCost'], 2);?> THB</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td style="text-align:right;"><?php  echo number_format($row['ExpenseCost'], 2);?> THB</td>
                </tr>
                <?php 
                $cnt=$cnt+1;
                }?>

                <tr>
                  <th colspan="2" style="text-align:left">Grand Total</th>     
                  <th></th>
                  <th style="text-align:right;"><?php echo number_format($total_i, 2);?> THB</th>
                  <th style="text-align:right;"><?php echo number_format($total_e, 2);?> THB</th>
                   <td style="text-align:right; font-weight:bold; background: yellow;"> <?php $ret=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ExpenseType, SUM(ExpenseCost) FROM tblexpense where (ExpenseDate BETWEEN '$fdate' and '$tdate')  && (ExpenseType='Expense') && UserId='$userid' ORDER BY ExpenseDate GROUP BY ExpenseType");
                        $e_sum = 0;
                       while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ret)) {
                        //$e_sum =  number_format($row['SUM(ExpenseCost)'], 2);
                        $e_sum =  $row['SUM(ExpenseCost)'];
                       }

                       ?>

                       <?php $ret=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ExpenseType, SUM(ExpenseCost) FROM tblexpense where (ExpenseDate BETWEEN '$fdate' and '$tdate')  && (ExpenseType='Income') && UserId='$userid'ORDER BY ExpenseDate  GROUP BY ExpenseType");
                       $i_sum = 0;
                        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ret)) {
                           //$i_sum =  number_format($row['SUM(ExpenseCost)'], 2);
                           $i_sum =  $row['SUM(ExpenseCost)'];

                        }
                        echo number_format($i_sum-$e_sum,2);
                        ?> THB</td>
                    </th>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>

            <!-- table end--->

        </div>
    </div>
```

Here a screenshot of the output:

[image]

Essentially the output and the values are correct, however, the 2 items I've marked in red (which are Cash out) are not sorted by date as my other values for expenses but add to the top. My ideal goal is to have them all sorted seamlessly by ExpenseDate. What's the best way to have this achieved? Some expert help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should merge your two queries into one, and then generate the table output based on the value of `ExpenseType` e.g.

```
$ret=mysqli_query($con,"select * 
                        from tblexpense 
                        where (ExpenseDate BETWEEN '$fdate' and '$tdate')  
                          and (ExpenseType='Expense' or ExpenseType='Income') 
                          and UserId='$userid'
                        ORDER BY ExpenseDate ASC");
```

then in your loop:

```
<tr>
  <td><?php  echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row["ExpenseDate"]));?></td>
  <td><?php  echo $row['ExpenseItem'];?></td>
  <td><?php  echo $row['ExpenseType'] = 'Expense' ? $row['ExpenseCat'] : '';?></td>
  <td style="text-align:right;"><?php  echo  $row['ExpenseType'] = 'Expense' ? '' : number_format($row['ExpenseCost'], 2); ?> THB</td>
  <td style="text-align:right;"><?php  echo  $row['ExpenseType'] = 'Expense' ? number_format($row['ExpenseCost'], 2) : '';?> THB</td>
  <td style="text-align:right;"><?php  echo number_format($row['ExpenseCost'], 2);?> THB</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you very much I will try your method

Comment: @sierra no worries - but you don't need to accept until you're sure it works.

Comment: I think you pointed me out in the right direction, so thank you very much for your help, appreciated!